# How to find the maximum of a function on a set of discrete points?

Tags: programming, functions, numerics

How to find the maximum of a function on a set of discrete points? For example, what is the best way to find the maximum of

```
-2 a - 2 b - 2 c - 2 d - 2 e - 2 f + e (-2 + d + f) - 2 g + f (-2 + a + e + g) - 
 2 h + c (-2 + b + d + h) - 2 i - 2 j + a (-2 + b + f + j) + i (-2 + h + j) + 
 h (-2 + c + g + i + j) - 2 k + d (-2 + c + e + k) + j (-2 + a + h + i + k) - 
 2 l + g (-2 + f + h + l) + k (-2 + d + j + l) - 2 m + (-2 + b + l) m + l 
 (-2 + b + g + k + m) + b (-2 + a + c + l + m)
```

where $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l, m \in \{-1,1\}$? Any help or suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: What about the other parameters ? Do they have a numeric value ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks All the parameters are -1 or 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the expression is slightly involved I'd put it in `Table` and write its all values for 
     `{a, {-1, 1}}, {b, {-1, 1}},..., {m, {-1, 1}}`

It can be done this way

```
With[{iter = 
      Sequence @@ Table[{var, {-1, 1}}, 
                        {var, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m}}]}, 
     With[{tab = 
           Table[{ -2 a - 2 b - 2 c - 2 d - 2 e - 2 f + e (-2 + d + f) - 2 g 
                   + f (-2 + a + e + g) - 2 h + c (-2 + b + d + h) - 2 i - 2 j 
                   + a (-2 + b + f + j) + i (-2 + h + j) + h (-2 + c + g + i + j) 
                   - 2 k + d (-2 + c + e + k) + j (-2 + a + h + i + k) - 2 l 
                   + g (-2 + f + h + l) + k (-2 + d + j + l) - 2 m + (-2 + b + l) m 
                   + l (-2 + b + g + k + m) + b (-2 + a + c + l + m), 
                  {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m}}, iter]}, 

           Cases[tab, {tab // Max, {___}}, Infinity]
         ]
    ]
```

> ```
> {{92, {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}}}
> ```

In more general cases you should consider writing your expression as a pure function and work with e.g. `Inner`, `Outer`, `Tuples`. What might be the best approach  depends on various issues, like e.g. the size of the underlying parameter space, etc..

Comment: Nice! But how to find the values of $a,b,c,\cdots,m$ for the maximal value?

Comment: `Cases[With[{w = 
    Sequence @@ 
     Table[{z, {-1, 1}}, {z, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, 
        m}}]}, Table[{-2 a - 2 b - 2 c - 2 d - 2 e - 2 f + 
     e (-2 + d + f) - 2 g + f (-2 + a + e + g) - 2 h + 
     c (-2 + b + d + h) - 2 i - 2 j + a (-2 + b + f + j) + 
     i (-2 + h + j) + h (-2 + c + g + i + j) - 2 k + 
     d (-2 + c + e + k) + j (-2 + a + h + i + k) - 2 l + 
     g (-2 + f + h + l) + k (-2 + d + j + l) - 2 m + (-2 + b + l) m + 
     l (-2 + b + g + k + m) + b (-2 + a + c + l + m), {a, b, c, d, e, 
     f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m}}, w]], {92, {___}}, Infinity]`

Comment: Yields `{{92, {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}}}`. But that was another question !

Comment: Is it possible to find the maximum and the corresponding points at the same time?

Comment: @EdenHarder Yes, of course, let me update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

One can take advantage of the [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Listable.html) properties of `Plus` and `Times`.  One can just feed the lists of input values into each of `a`, `b`, etc.  `Tuples` yields all possible combinations of `{1, -1}` and `Transpose` collects all the inputs for `a`, `b`, etc. respectively into lists to feed into the function `fn`:

```
expr = -2 a - 2 b - 2 c - 2 d - 2 e - 2 f + e (-2 + d + f) - 2 g + 
   f (-2 + a + e + g) - 2 h + c (-2 + b + d + h) - 2 i - 2 j + 
   a (-2 + b + f + j) + i (-2 + h + j) + h (-2 + c + g + i + j) - 
   2 k + d (-2 + c + e + k) + j (-2 + a + h + i + k) - 2 l + 
   g (-2 + f + h + l) + k (-2 + d + j + l) - 2 m + (-2 + b + l) m + 
   l (-2 + b + g + k + m) + b (-2 + a + c + l + m);

fn = Function @@ {Variables@expr, expr}  (* Variables will put them in alpha. order *)
fn @@ Transpose@Tuples[{1, -1}, 13] // Max 
(* 92 *)
```

You can use `Pick` as does @Verbeia to select the input(s) that gives the maximum.

```
values = fn @@ Transpose[tuples = Tuples[{1, -1}, 13]];
Pick[tuples, values, Max@values]
(* {{-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}} *)
```

Or to get the maximum and input at the same time:

```
values = fn @@ Transpose[tuples = Tuples[{1, -1}, 13]];
With[{max = Max@values},
  {max, Pick[tuples, values, max]}
]
(* {92, {{-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Will this code be better in speed? And can we find the maximum and the corresponding points at the same time?

Comment: This code should be about the fastest way to find the maximum of all the values.  A particular function might have a special form that allows for a faster algorithm to be applied.  It's quite easy to get the max. and points at the same time.  See the update

Answer (score 2):

Because your set of discrete points is very long (13 variables each with two possible values = $2^{13}$ = 8192, I will demonstrate an approach with a simpler case.

First, you can get your values using `Tuples`:

```
tups = Tuples[{-1, 1}, 3]
```

> {{-1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1}, {-1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1,  1}, 
>      {1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}}

If you recast your problem as a pure function, you can then apply that function to each case like this:

```
values= #1 + #2 + #3 & @@@ tups
```

> {-3, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 3}

You can then use `Pick` to select the combination of parameters that generates the maximum value:

```
Pick[tups, values, Max[values]]
```

> {{1, 1, 1}}

Answer (score 1):

This will probably not work for much bigger problems :

```
Maximize[{-2 a - 2 b - 2 c - 2 d - 2 e - 2 f + e (-2 + d + f) - 2 g + 
          f (-2 + a + e + g) - 2 h + c (-2 + b + d + h) - 2 i - 2 j + 
          a (-2 + b + f + j) + i (-2 + h + j) + h (-2 + c + g + i + j) - 
          2 k + d (-2 + c + e + k) + j (-2 + a + h + i + k) - 2 l + 
          g (-2 + f + h + l) + k (-2 + d + j + l) - 2 m + (-2 + b + l) m + l
          (-2 + b + g + k + m) + b (-2 + a + c + l + m), -1 == a || 
          1 == a, -1 == b || 1 == b, -1 == c || 1 == c, -1 == d || 
          1 == d, -1 == e || 1 == e, -1 == f || 1 == f, -1 == g || 
          1 == g, -1 == h || 1 == h, -1 == i || 1 == i, -1 == j || 
          1 == j, -1 == k || 1 == k, -1 == l || 1 == l, -1 == m || 
          1 == m}, 
       {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m}, Integers]
(* {92, {a -> -1, b -> -1, c -> -1, d -> -1, e -> -1, f -> -1, g -> -1, 
    h -> -1, i -> -1, j -> -1, k -> -1, l -> -1, m -> -1}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks! why the code is '-1 == a || 1 == a' instead of 'a == -1 || a == 1'?

Comment: No reason at all.